# jquery sort multiple lists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to sort several ULs with jquery. The criteria is that the LI containing the text "current" must be moved to the top of that list.

example

```
<ul>
    <li>doc1</li>
    <li>doc5</li>
    <li>doc3</li>
    <li>doc54 (current)</li>
    <li>doc1</li>
</ul>
```

would become

```
<ul>
    <li>doc54 (current)</li>
    <li>doc1</li>
    <li>doc5</li>
    <li>doc3</li>
    <li>doc1</li>
</ul>
```

(but there are many of these lists on the page, all different and not always containing an item which is labeled "current" which all must be sorted)

Help would be appreciated. JSFiddles even more appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$('li:contains("current")').each(function () {
  $(this).insertBefore(
    $(this).parent().children().not(this).eq(0)
  );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D2EkM/4/

Comment: slight bug in your code. - if there is only one entry with the word "current" it deletes it out of the list!

Comment: well done, your update also includes cases where it is first in list, not just only in list like my edit did.